# Please, Explain a one of feature singleton(C++)

Tags: c++, singleton

For example I have a following class:

```
class singelton
{
public:
    static singelton* Instance()
    {
        if (m_pInstance == 0)
        {
            m_pInstance = new singelton();
        }
        return m_pInstance;
    }

    void setData(std::string input) { data = input; }
    void getData() const { std::cout << data << std::endl; }
private:
    singelton() {}
    ~singelton() {}

    static singelton* m_pInstance;

    std::string data;
};

typedef singelton s;

//what is this? Why need a singleton name? I mean "singelton*".
singelton* singelton::m_pInstance = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    s.Instance()->setData("Something...");
    s.Instance()->getData();
    return 0;
}
```

What is `singelton* singelton::m_pInstance = 0;`?
This function assigns zero/null to a singleton instance, but why need use `singleton*` ? That assignment like a function, but use as assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static data members are not part of objects of a given class type; they are separate objects. As a result, the declaration of a static data member is not considered a definition. So static member must be defined outside of the class declaration.

In your example:

- `singelton *` is a type of member.
- `singleton::` is class name (like namespace)
- and `m_pInstance` is member name

**P.S.:** Because of static variables are initialised with 0 by default in C++, you don't need to explicitly set `m_pInstance` to `0` (or `NULL`). The definition only will be enough:

```
singelton * singelton::m_pInstance;
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is `singelton* singelton::m_pInstance = 0;`?

It's the initialiser for the static member variable `m_pInstance`, statically initialising the pointer to be null. `singelton*` (pointer to singelton) is the type of the variable; `singlelton::m_pInstance` is the (qualified) name of the variable; and `= 0` is the initialiser.

> This function assigns zero/null to a singleton instance, but why need use `singleton*` ?

No, it initialises the pointer to null; it doesn't point to anything yet. The object itself will be created, and the pointer updated to point to it, the first time someone calls `Instance()`. It's a pointer so that the object itself can be created when it's first needed, rather than at some arbitrary point during program startup - this is known as "lazy initialisation".

Beware that, in C++, there is no way to implement the Singleton anti-pattern correctly. This particular implementation has the problems of leaking the object, and not being thread-safe. I strongly recommend that you get rid of it: just instantiate the object in an appropriate place, with a lifetime that's longer than whatever uses it, and pass references to whatever needs it.

Comment: Could you please comment a bit more on why you consider singleton an _anti-pattern_?

Comment: @Massimiliano: That's beyond the scope of the question, and is well covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/), although that only discusses the conceptual problems of the anti-pattern in general, not the impossibility of implementing it correctly in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Singleton::Instance()->setData("Hello");
```

and

```
Singleton::Instance()->getData();
```

The class can only have one instance - hence called singleton

And the `Singleton::Instance` gives you access to that

```
singelton* singelton::m_pInstance = 0;
```

Initializes it and when you first use it the singleton is created